# По id vk вернуть имя и фамилию

Tags: android, java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу приложение для Android. Есть массив id. Хочу получить имя и фамилию! Авторизироваться вроде получается, а что дальше?

Answer (score 13):

1.Получаешь `access_token`

```
http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id="ID_приложения"&scope=12&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=touch&response_type=token
```

Получаешь ответ вида:

```
access_token=1543b2375a85aded15b8440eae15cc1506115e715e798cccb2e3c67351ba57f&expires_in=86300&user_id=18791
```

2.Делаешь запрос:

```
 https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uid=18791&access_token=1543b2375a85aded15b8440eae15cc1506115e715e798cccb2e3c67351ba57f
```

Получаешь ответ

```
{"response":[{"uid":10758791,"first_name":"Вася","last_name":"Пупкин"}]}
```

Если нужен ответ в xml, то

```
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles.xml?uid=18791&access_token=1543b2375a85aded15b8440eae15cc1506115e715e798cccb2e3c67351ba57f
```

Получится

```
<response list="true">
  <user>
    <uid>18791</uid>
    <first_name>Вася</first_name>
    <last_name>Пупкин</last_name>
  </user>
</response>
```

для получения информации о нескольких юзерах лучше использовать users.get. Параметр uids - через запятую ID пользователей (до 1000)

```
 https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=123456,321456,369852,741258&access_token=9412a33ddb45b05564751cb2f5940d060599426942689b6a9085feac5ce35a4
```

Comment: Получил client_id 
делаю запрос для access_token, получаю
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"client_id is incorrect"}

Comment: client_id это семизначное число, в строку запроса вставляется без кавычек, у Вас так?

Comment: Да............

Comment: Можно взглянуть?

Comment: 2854847
Может я что то не так делаю? отправляю пост запрос с логином и паролем, в ответ получаю исходный код страницы!(вроде авторизировался) потом отправляю ваш запрос и ничего! Если я ввожу запрос в браузере он мне предлагает разрешить доступ, но я пишу приложение, где нет ни окна браузера ни webview!

Comment: Без разрешения конкретного пользователя доступ приложения к API закрыт.
Есть еще Авторизация сервера
http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=Авторизация сервера приложения
но там я не понял, что за  параметр grant_type = "client_credentials"

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете провести запрос без авторизации который выглядит следующим образом.

```
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uids=твой id&fields=photo
```

В общем Вы можете пользоваться всеми функциями метода getProfiles описанного в докуметации к vk.com api. Таким обазом можно получить имя, фамилию, фотографию пользователя, информацию о том находиться ли он в сети в момент запроса.

Comment: Круто! Спасибо! А в документации везде ACCESS_TOKEN в запросе.
Только uids - не "твой id", а список id через запятую.
а значения параметра fields тут http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=Описание_полей_параметра_fields

Comment: Имейте ввиду что это устаревшая версия api. Лучшим решением будет применить авторизацию через OAuth с приведенным выше тоекном.