# Получение токена VK

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Привет. Помогите реализовать получение токена ВК. Попробовал около 4 кодов/способов - не работает что-то, ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/89614#89673

Comment: @katso Я знаю, как происходит процесс получения токена. Но вот реализации на Java я там не вижу

Comment: @thejadefalcon

Ну, поглядите исходники Vk Android SDK

https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk

Comment: @thejadefalcon, как получить токен, вы знаете, тогда, я полагаю, вы не знаете, как отправить get-запрос в java?

Comment: @katso Там, ведь нужно, чтобы пользователь руками нажал "Разрешить", и только потом после редиректа дается токен. Не понимаю, как это возможно сделать в Java.